# IE11 Flexbox layout broken in scrolling container

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I do have a flexbox-container which should contain two elements. Both of them can have dynamic content, which means the height cannot be specified.

The container should have a maximum height of 400px and a maximum width of 300px. In case the height of the two elements should be larger than 400px, a scrollbar should appear. There should never be a scrollbar on the X-axis.

Here Is my code:

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}

.element1 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.element2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.subelement {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  </div>

  <div class="element2">
    <div class="subelement">Reply</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works fine in Chrome, here the result:

[image: Rendering in Chrome]

This does not work in in IE 11, here the result:

[image]

For some unknown reason the first element takes as much horizontal space as somehow possible and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

Any tip how to get the same behaviour in IE 11 as we have in chrome?

Here is a running plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nJiXeFHzFzL2L5DsRJvi?p=info

Comment: The posted code works as is in IE 11.

Comment: And do note, IE11 has issue with jsfiddle, codepen, plnkr, etc., and is not a trustworthy place to test at.

Comment: @LGSon Thx for your feedback.Did you run the plunkr? It does definitly not work. Did you check it in IE 11? What is your Version? Mine is 11.379.17763.0 running on Win 10.

Comment: Plnkr doesn't even load in my IE11, which btw has the same version number as yours, on Win 10. The inline snippet I made with your code sample works just fine on IE 11.

Comment: How did you check it then? Copy paste the complete code into an HTML file and run it locally does exactly show the issue which I posted above?

Comment: You can't just copy that code, it doesn't have a `doctype`, nor does your plnkr. Still, it appears the posted answer solves it, it still works in the snippet though.

Comment: You are right, I missed that one in my sample code. But I'm glad that Hassan already spotted my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `width: 100%;` from `.element1` will resolve your issue. Thanks

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid violet;
}

.element1 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.element2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.subelement {
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
  </div>

  <div class="element2">
    <div class="subelement">Reply</div>
  </div>
</div>
```